# Most efficient way, performance-wise, to set up user permissions in a database?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

Of these two different method, which one should perform better when querying in a SQL Server database?  The first method seems more relational and "correct" and can be managed by an interface so that new permission can be added programmatically.  We use SQL Server with Entity Framework 6 but that probably doesn't matter too much.

```
USER TABLE
----------
UserID
FirstName
LastName
etc...


PERM TABLE
---------
PermID
PermName
etc...


USERPERM TABLE
----------
UserPermID
UserID
PermID
```

Or would this be a more efficient approach?  It would have to be manually managed if a new permission was introduced, but if it's a LOT more efficient to query, it might be worth it to have the management headache because these tables would have to be hit constantly.

```
USER TABLE
----------
UserID
FirstName
LastName
etc...


USERPERM TABLE
----------
UserPermID
UserID
HasManageUserPerm
HasManageGroupPerm
HasManageDocumentPerm
HasManageEmailTemplatePerm
HasManageBrandingPerm
HasManageProcessPerm
HasManageWebFormPerm
etc.
```

Comment: I like the first one, but without the UserPermID fields in the last table.

Comment: yeah, and just have a double PK?

Comment: lol, I knew I was going down-votes on this one but I still feel like it's an answerable question (and not opinion) that has value to the community and there are a ton of "most efficient way" questions with up-votes so screw-em. :)

Comment: Echo Dan Bracuk...though I'd think the userpermID as a pk on that table would have some value if you wanted to look up userperm records by a unique ID.

Comment: @Twelfth yeah, that's why I usually always have an identity PK.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences between each of your two schemas. However, these differences are negligible and will not "make or break" your database or application in any way. Therefore, it does not matter which you use.

### Schema 1

**Pros:**

- Could be considered more normalized due to the fact that Permissions are broken out into their own table. As a result, it is very clear what Permissions are and how they fit into the overall database schema.
- Queries on USERPERM return only the needed rows.

**Cons:**

- Difficult to quickly see what Permissions a User has, as each is represented by it's own record in the database.
- Most queries require at least one `JOIN` statement.

### Schema 2

**Pros:**

- Easy to see what Permissions a User has.
- Requires no `JOIN` statements to view Permission data.

**Cons:**

- A query on the USERPERM table will return all of the permission columns, which is more data to load and look at.
- Renaming or deleting a Permission will require the editing or deleting of an entire column.

If it means anything to you, your first schema is more "traditional" in terms of relational database schemas. Hope this helps.